# Moving PHP framework from one host to another, generates Uknown record property / related component error

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine

I need to move a website from one hosting to another, there is a php app that uses the Zend framework. 
Moving the files and the database i managed to reconfigure the database access, however an error appears on the page:

```
Fatal error: 
Uncaught Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException: Unknown record property / related component "Array" on "Model_User_Group" in /home/oneclou3/public_html/app/library/Doctrine/Record/Filter/Standard.php:55
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/oneclou3/public_html/app/library/Doctrine/Record.php(1395): Doctrine_Record_Filter_Standard->filterGet(Object(Model_User_Group), 'Array') 

#1 /home/oneclou3/public_html/app/library/Doctrine/Record.php(1350): Doctrine_Record->_get('Array', true) 

#2 /home/oneclou3/public_html/app/library/Doctrine/Access.php(72): Doctrine_Record->get('Array') 

#3 /home/oneclou3/public_html/app/library/Doctrine/Query/Abstract.php(1121): Doctrine_Access->__get('Array') 

#4 /home/oneclou3/public_html/app/library/Doctrine/Query/Abstract.php(1008): Doctrine_Query_Abstract->_preQuery(Array) 

#5 /home/oneclou3/public_html/app/library/Doctrine/Table.php(1649): Doctrine_Query_Abstract->execute(Array, 3) 

#6 /home/oneclou3/public_html/app/library/Zex/Auth/Abstract.php(229): Doctrine_Table->findAll(3) 

#7 /home/oneclou3/p in /home/oneclou3/public_html/app/library/Doctrine/Record/Filter/Standard.php on line 55
```

I'm not sure how to solve this, the Model_User_Group just extends a base class:

```
<?php
/**
 * Model_User_Group
 * 
 * This class has been auto-generated by the Doctrine ORM Framework
 * 
 * @package    ##PACKAGE##
 * @subpackage ##SUBPACKAGE##
 * @author     ##NAME## <##EMAIL##>
 * @version    SVN: $Id: Builder.php 7490 2010-03-29 19:53:27Z jwage $
 */
class Model_User_Group extends BaseModel_User_Group
{

}
```

base:

```
<?php

/**
 * BaseModel_User_Group
 * 
 * This class has been auto-generated by the Doctrine ORM Framework
 * 
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $title
 * @property string $uid
 * @property string $model
 * @property Doctrine_Collection $Model_User
 * 
 * @package    ##PACKAGE##
 * @subpackage ##SUBPACKAGE##
 * @author     ##NAME## <##EMAIL##>
 * @version    SVN: $Id: Builder.php 7490 2010-03-29 19:53:27Z jwage $
 */
abstract class BaseModel_User_Group extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->setTableName('groups');
        $this->hasColumn('id', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'primary' => true,
             'autoincrement' => true,
             'length' => '4',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('title', 'string', 255, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'notnull' => true,
             'length' => '255',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('uid', 'string', 50, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'notnull' => true,
             'length' => '50',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('model', 'string', 255, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'notnull' => true,
             'length' => '255',
             ));


        $this->index('uid', array(
             'fields' => 
             array(
              0 => 'uid',
             ),
             'type' => 'unique',
             ));
        $this->option('collate', 'utf8_general_ci');
        $this->option('charset', 'utf8');
        $this->option('type', 'InnoDB');
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->hasMany('Model_User', array(
             'local' => 'id',
             'foreign' => 'groups_id'));

        $timestampable0 = new Doctrine_Template_Timestampable();
        $this->actAs($timestampable0);
    }
}
```

Not sure what else i need to provide, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you use Magento ?

Comment: No, it doesn't use magento